# Binary search in an array with boolean values

Tags: java, binary-search

I have an array with boolean values. But sequence of elements like these:
first go `true` values, and then `false` values.
For example,

```
boolean[] booleans = {true, true, true, true, true,
                false, false, false, false, false, false};
```

So now we have a sorted array with boolean values, starting with `true` values if `true` value exists.

**The task is to find first `false` element.**
I created a class with search method using binary search algorithm.

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public static int search(boolean[] array) {

        int low = 0, mid = 0;
        int high = array.length - 1;
        boolean booleanValue;

        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            booleanValue = array[mid];
            if (booleanValue) low = mid + 1;
            else high = mid - 1;
        }

        return mid == array.length - 1 ? -(low + 1) : mid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[] booleans = {true, true, true, true, true,
                false, false, false, false, false, false};

        int search = search(booleans);
        System.out.println("search = " + search);
    }
}
```

It is not working correct, i.e. sometimes it is returning previous element of searched one.
Finding element by searching iteratively is also not good idea, because array's size could be really big, and it will take much time.

**Edit:** Actually I need to search in MySQL database table. But table size is too big, and finding required row takes to much time, I want to use binary search algorithm for fastening.
**Edit:** MySQL table size more than 45 million rows. It takes about 30 seconds when searching required row by SQL query, no matter I added index to the column or not. Furthermore adding index in `boolean` doesn't give any effect.
When I use binary search it takes about 10 milliseconds. So I want the above method to be corrected.
**Edit:** For instance, I have DB table called "INFORMATION". And it has two columns "INFO" (TEXT) and "CHECKED" (BOOLEAN). Initial values of "INFO"s are `false`. And I will get first unchecked info, and get N rows starting from unchecked, then I will check them and mark them `true`. Process will be repeated until there is no unchecked infos.

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: And searching about the bug when the size is an odd number ? I don't see a question so I write this one ;)

Comment: @AxelH to find first false element

Comment: Why would you use Binary search to find the first false element?!!

Comment: @Null because it's asymptotically faster than a linear probe...?

Comment: @AndyTurner is it even possible ?? i mean; the data must be ordered in order to apply binary search, am i right ?

Comment: @Null well, obviously. But look at the example data.

Comment: "But table size is too big, and finding required row takes to much time, I want to use binary search algorithm for fastening." You should add an index then, so that the database engine can find it for you.

Comment: @AndyTurner index will require more space, right? Actually I can add index, but how about binary search?

Comment: Why do you need to worry about the algorithm? `SELECT * FROM table WHERE booleanField LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I added index, but select result took about 30 seconds.

Comment: @pyramidPeak if adding an index is that slow, reading the data and searching it manually is unlikely to be faster.

Comment: @AndyTurner I mean searching (selecting) took 30 seconds after adding index.

Comment: And I mean if it's that slow after adding the index, reading the data and searching it manually is unlikely to be faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134493/discussion-between-pyramidpeak-and-andy-turner).

Comment: @AndyTurner But with binary search it takes about 10 ms.

Comment: Then you've probably not added the right index.

Comment: ALTER TABLE \`TABLE_NAME\`
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (\`ID\`, \`CHECKED\`);

Comment: @pyramidPeak right, so that primary key sorts first by `ID`, then `CHECKED`. For it to be fast, you want `CHECKED` to be first (but it's probably not the primary key you want to use).

Comment: @Andy I want to use both of them. That's the problem.

Comment: Does the word "primary" in "primary key" not imply to you that there can be other keys? I mean, I never use MySQL, so I don't know for sure; but if they're not supported, that's a very good reason to get onto a better DB.

Comment: Just for information, on some DB, index on a bit is complete useless, some don't even accept it (sybase refuse bit column on INDEX). So I would don't add the index on it if you see it take to much time.

Comment: Do you know that the `true` values are all at the front of the array? How can you guarantee that a binary search will **always** give you the first `false` value? For example, what if the array only has `false`. Will a binary search give you the first element? Or will it give you the element at `n/2`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, `true` values are always will be at the front. and when an array has only `false` values binary search should give first element.

Comment: "when an array has only false values binary search should give first element" Why? A binary search will look at element `n/2` first. This element has the value of `false`, so therefore the search will return `n/2`, not 0 as it should.

Comment: because I need to find first `false` value.

Comment: So you are saying that you want to drive from New York to Los Angeles, but driving to Boston is faster...

Comment: I think binary search might not be appropriate solution for your requirement please switch to Linear Search. Since Binary search logic is something different of what you intended to do.

Comment: I think the bug is in the line `else high = mid - 1;`. I think it needs to be `else high = mid;`

Comment: nevermind. I understand how you can make a modified binary search do what you want. I suggest you use a debugger to figure out what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I amended the ***Xin Huang*** answer and simplified the code a bit:

```
public static int search(boolean[] array) {

    int low = 0, mid;
    int high = array.length - 1;
    boolean booleanValue;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        booleanValue = array[mid];
        if (booleanValue) low = mid + 1;
        else if (low == mid) return mid;
        else high = mid;
    }
    return -low;
}
```

So now the method is returning index of first `false` element in the array if element found, and negative value if element not found.

Answer (score 1):

During loop, if booleanValue is false

1. if low = mid, starting point and ending point meets, we found what we need
2. else high = mid since mid is definitely a potential candidate

Modified as below:

```
    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        booleanValue = array[mid];
        if (booleanValue) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else {
            if (low == mid) {
                break;
            }
            high = mid;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code still has a bug when all values == true. You may want to update your return for special case `mid == array.length -1`.

Comment: please change `if (low == mid) { break;}` to `if (low == mid) return mid`, and last return to `return -(low + 1);`